# pfSense 2.2: HAProxy for HTTP + CARP + MultiWAN with VIPs issue (Outbound NAT?)

Tags: routing, haproxy, pfsense, carp

I have two pfSense firewalls with CARP setup, 2 WANs and HAProxy that points to HTTP servers in my LAN.

**Scheme:**

```
**pfSense server #1**
ISP#1 - Public IP1.1 - pfSense#1 with HAProxy - HTTP
ISP#2 - Public IP1.2 - **ISP#2 Local IP1** - pfSense#1 with HAProxy - HTTP
LAN vIP - pfSense as Gateway (Master)

**pfSense server #2**
ISP#1 - Public IP2.1 - pfSense#2 with HAProxy - HTTP
ISP#2 - Public IP2.2 - **ISP#2 Local IP2** - pfSense#2 with HAProxy - HTTP
```

All LAN servers and PCs GW set as LAN vIP that migrates via CARP.

**Problem:**
When I'm trying to access HTTP servers via IPs:

```
Public IP1.1 -> OK
Public IP1.2 -> OK
Public IP2.1 -> OK
ISP#2 Local IP1 -> OK
ISP#2 Local IP2 -> OK
**Public IP2.2 -> FAILED**
```

How can I get Public IP2.2 accessible?

I think it's some king of outbound NAT issue, but I can't figure it out how to set it up. Need help!

*P.s. pfSense v2.2, latest build, VM @ Hyper-V*

Comment: Problem solved. NAT problem was found for ISP#2.